# How to elongate the branches attached to one specific node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

[image]

I'd like to make longer only two immediate branches attached to the VP node (red ones in the picture) without altering the height of the other branches above and below. Any idea? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\tikzset{every tree edge/.style={align=center, anchor=north}} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree
      [.TP
            [.DP \edge[roof]; {Harvey} ]
            [.T\1
                [.T {[past]} ]
                [.{VP \\ <e,t>}
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {t$_1$} ]
                    [.V\1
                        [.V {eat} ]
                        [.DP ]]]]]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you could make your sample document compilable (*i.e.*, complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required package(s), `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by make the branches longer without altering the height of the other branches? Making them longer will require moving `DP` and `V'` further down. Or do you want to make them longer by moving `DP` and `V'` further to the left and right, respectively?

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @AdamLiter Good point. I assumed it meant make those longer without making the level distance for any other level larger i.e. move stuff down but only enough to make just these two branches longer. But you're right - it could mean increase the distance between the two immediate children. (But that would make some other branches longer as you'd have to spread the tree more to avoid overlaps, right?)

Comment: @cfr Yes, it would increase the separation of all sibling nodes above this particular level.

Comment: @AdamLiter I wanted the two red immediate branches under the VP node only without affecting the others because they got shorter since I put one line more (<e,t>) at the VP node.

Comment: @cfr If I use \tikzset{level distance=55pt}, all the branches get longer than I want. So, I asked this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target particular levels with `\tikzset`. Note, however, that this also increases the separation of `[past]` from `T`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\tikzset{level 3/.style={level distance=5em}} % the root of the tree is level 0
\Tree
    [.TP
        [.DP \edge[roof]; {Harvey} ]
        [.T\1
            [.T {[past]} ]
            [.VP\\$<e,t>$
                [.DP \edge[roof]; {t$_1$} ]
                [.V\1
                    [.V {eat} ]
                    [.DP ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There are two workarounds that I can think of off the top of my head. First, you could make `[past]` part of the same node.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\tikzset{level 3/.style={level distance=5em}}
\Tree
    [.TP
        [.DP \edge[roof]; {Harvey} ]
        [.T\1
            [.T\\{[past]} ] % note the difference here
            [.VP\\$<e,t>$
                [.DP \edge[roof]; {t$_1$} ]
                [.V\1
                    [.V {eat} ]
                    [.DP ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could manually shift `[past]` using the `yshift` key.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\tikzset{level 3/.style={level distance=5em}}
\Tree
    [.TP
        [.DP \edge[roof]; {Harvey} ]
        [.T\1
            [.T \node[yshift=2em]{[past]}; ] % note the difference here
            [.VP\\$<e,t>$
                [.DP \edge[roof]; {t$_1$} ]
                [.V\1
                    [.V {eat} ]
                    [.DP ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Other than that, using `forest` might be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I should migrate to forest before I get too used to tike-qtree. :)

Comment: @mangotango No problem. I thought of another solution for `[past]`, but, ultimately, I'd recommend using `forest`. I've recently transitioned myself! `:)`

Comment: Okie. Have a good weekend! :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind switching packages, `forest` specialises in this kind of customisation:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
  }
  [TP
    [DP
      [Harvey, triangle]
    ]
    [T%\1
        [T
        [{[past]}]
        ]
        [VP, l sep+=\baselineskip
            [DP
              [{t$_1$}, triangle]
            ]
            [V%\1
                [V
                  [eat]
                ]
                [DP ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: longer forest branches]

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there any way in the same package I use now? I am a novice, so changing packages would confuse me more.

Comment: @mangotango The syntax of `forest` is very similar to `tikz-qtree`. But, I've provided an answer that does this in `tikz-qtree`.

Comment: @AdamLiter Yeah, I am reading the forest manual now. :) Thanks all of you.

Comment: @mangotango It is not too hard to do the basic migration. Just don't be put off by the length of the manual. You don't need most of it to typeset basic trees. (I migrated from `qtree` rather than `tikz-qtree` but the syntax of all these seems similar.)